# QUERY Ranges of Dates Using Contains

Tags: sql, google-sheets-formula

I want to check data filtering by range of dates from data pulled by the QUERY in Google Sheets

I need to apply this part of the formula **F>=date** ...

But the problem I'm encountering is that the date column in raw data has dates in text format like this "2020-04-22 13:34:03".

I can filter data from one specific day using CONTAINS but how do I insert the function >=date to check ranges of dates?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that that particular date format will sort alphabetically exactly as it would by date. So depending what you're comparing to, do you even care about it not being a date (eg. if it's a hardcoded value, can you just write `F>='2020-01-01 00:00:00'`)? Otherwise, you can convert the right side of your equation with `text` like `F >= text(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` or convert the left side with something like `TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(F)) > ...`

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't care if it's a date, I just want the query to search ranges of dates that I add to the concatenated cell. My formula looks like this:

=QUERY(RAWDATA!A1:M3258,"SELECT A,B,D,G,F,K,L WHERE 

  F contains '"&TEXTO(C4,"YYYY")&"-"&TEXTO(C4,"MM")&"-"&TEXTO(C4,"DD")&"'

",1)

and now returns the date that is found in cell C4, but since I'm using contains because the raw date date include hours, minutes, and seconds, it only returns data that contains the date yyyy-mm-dd. I have no idea how to insert >= in order to return the date in cell C4 or later dates.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A:F, F:F*1},  "where Col7 >="&TODAY()*1))
```